# Write permissions on a new encrypted partition

Tags: filevault

The HD of my MacBook Pro (macOS Mojave) is encrypted with FileVault.

Yesterday, I created a new partition from the Macintosh HD (APFS) using the DiskUtility and called the new partition **Data** (Extended Journaled).

The problem is that now I cannot copy any files to the new partition. It seems that I don't have write permissions to write anything on the new partition.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from Disk Utility or the result of `diskutil list` to throw some light on your disk structure? The output of `mount` would help as well. Also, did you create the new partition *on* your main drive (and therefore reduced the size of the existing one) or on an external drive?

Comment: I added some screen shots. By partitioning I had the choice between Partition and Add-Volume. I selected the Partition option. Not sure if this is the best option though.

Comment: okay. your question was misleading atleast for me. Your data folder is also on APFS but in your question, it was Extended Journaled. I will try to see this.

Comment: It doesn't matter which file system. I can format Data partition to whatever file system but it's always Read-Only.

Comment: @user1941537: have you try this from terminal: sudo mount -u -w -v "/Volumes/Data" ? This should allow you to write.

Answer (score -1):

I assume this happened as you have used the partition on Extended Journaled

Open the finder, find the drive under ‘**Devices**’, then right-click and select ‘**Get Info**’.  A dialog box should pop up and display the basic info of the drive. At the bottom, there is a collapsed menu for ‘**Sharing & Permissions**’, make sure your username has read and write permission, and check "**Ignore ownership on this volume**"

[image]

If you are unable to do this , then first try to disable Journaling, and do the previous step shared above

Open **Disk Utility**, Select the partition and then hold down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. Select the file from the top menu and you will then see an option to ‘disable Journalling’

Comment: How does the problem described in the question relate to "Extended Journaled" and ownership? How does enabling journaling cause access issues in the first place?

Comment: I was able to enable "Ignore ownership on this volume" but it didn't help. I also added some screen shots to my original post, which might help. By partitioning I had the choice between Partition and Add-Volume and I selected the Partition option. Not sure if this is the best option though.